# Torsion submodules in an Integral Domain

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be an integral domain and $M$ an $R$-module. By definition, a torsion element is an element $m \in M$ such that $rm=0$ for some non-zero element $r \in R$.

Here is my confusion: Since there are no zero divisors in an integral domain, if we want $rm=0$ where $r \neq 0$,  isn't the only possible element $m =0$, meaning the only torsion element is $0 \in M$? Thus, isn't the torsion submodule of $M$ the singleton containing $0$??

I've been confused about this and would appreciate any help!

Comment: $\mathbb{Z} / m \mathbb{Z}$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if you’re stuck thinking $m\in R$ for some reason.

There are lots of examples of modules over a domain that have torsion. Take a proper nonzero ideal $I$ and look at $R/I$ as an $R$ module, for instance.

Comment: Thank you! You're right, I was only thinking about M as a particular set (ex., the integers).